# Why is the console application giving an error

Tags: c#, console-application

I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CheckAndCreateFolder("C:\\FolderCreate");
            CheckAndCreateFolder("C:\\FolderCreate2");
            CheckAndCreateFolder("C:\\FolderCreate3");
            CheckAndCreateFolder("C:\\FolderCreate4");
        }
    }
    public class CheckAndCreateFolder(string p)
    {
           if (!Directory.Exists(p)) {
                  Directory.CreateDirectory(p);
           }
    }
}
```

I am getting `Invalid token in '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration` and other errors.

My application is trying to create a directory if it doesn't exist.

How can I resolve the error.

Comment: You have defined `CheckAndCreateFolder` as a class instead of a method.  If it is intended to be a method it should be inside a class definition.

Comment: That's a compilation error, so it is not related to creating the directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have defined your class is not correct.

```
public class CheckAndCreateFolder(string p)
{
       if (!Directory.Exists(p)) {
              Directory.CreateDirectory(p);
       }
}
```

This should be a method.

```
static void CheckAndCreateFolder(string p)
{
       if (!Directory.Exists(p)) {
              Directory.CreateDirectory(p);
       }
}
```

and it should be added inside the class called `Program`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CheckAndCreateFolder("C:\\FolderCreate");
        CheckAndCreateFolder("C:\\FolderCreate2");
        CheckAndCreateFolder("C:\\FolderCreate3");
        CheckAndCreateFolder("C:\\FolderCreate4");
    }

    static void CheckAndCreateFolder(string p)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(p)) 
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had a tiny mistake in the code.